# C# DataGridView cell autoComplete does not display with EditControlShowing

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

The goal is to type into the any cell for autocomplete under a dgv column. But the list does not appear after typing 't'. After adding a breakpoint, I found that when I select a cell, it fired the EditControlShowing eventhandler before I even begin to type. When I type, the EditingControlShowing code is never stepped into again.

I do have other cell click and cell enter event handler linked to the same dgv. But I doubt they interfered with this.

```
private void dataGridView_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
    int rowIndex = dataGridView.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
    int columnIndex = dataGridView.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;
    string columnName = dataGridView.Columns[columnIndex].Name;
    if (columnName == "ColumnName")
    {
        var box = (TextBox)e.Control;
        box.AutoCompleteCustomSource = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
        box.AutoCompleteCustomSource.AddRange(new string[] { "Text1", "Text2", "Text3" });
        box.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
        box.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi JohnG, thanks for pointing it out I made the changes. I don't think there is textbox in my datagridview. Input is entered directly into datagridview cell itself, which is bound to database.

Comment: Sorry, didn't realise editing question deletes the comments.

Comment: It didn't I did. This seems like an odd requirement. What is it that you want each cell in the "ColumnName" column to contain.?

Comment: It will be list of names from database. So I can type and it will suggest the names for me. I used Text1, Text2,Text3 as testing for now.

Comment: Are each cells auto complete values unique or are they all the same? If they are all the same, then I am guessing a combo box may be a more appropriate control. This is also dependent on how many “different” auto complete items there are. The current code appears to run correctly, however if they are all the same, then you may want to set this up on the form load and when new rows are added.

Comment: The list is the same for the entire column, but I prefer not  to use combobox because the list is very long.